# Metadata in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, metadata, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to fetch the metadata of my Bigquery tables and for this, I need to fetch the total no of rows which were inserted during last modified timestamp. Does this also come under as Metadata?

Also, I would need to have metadata for both Batching as well as Streaming. How can we find it out if it is batching or streaming data?

It would be really helpful if someone helps me in the architecture as well, as I need to send some alerting via email.

Currently I am trying like CloudScheduler --> Cloud Functions --> Pubsub --> Cloud function  --> ALerting via email.

Looking forward to many responses.

Comment: Does this can help? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-streaming

Comment: Yes, I had already seen this link. But the question is that, how can I check the total new row_count for any table metadata (batch) for that modified timestamp.

I am able to get the total_rows on a whole as a part of metadata but i am more concerned for the total which were inserted latest.

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't this kind of metadata

Comment: Okay.. But how do we do in general? I should implement monitoring for the BQ dataset tables where if the data is inserted or any errors, I should get it in dashboard about this and I can inform stakeholders that there is an issue with them.

Comment: Can you monitor the logs? You can imagine to create a filter in the logs on specific error case, and sink the result in BigQuery. Then you can create dashboard on this error table. Or use cloud monitoring to create Cloud Operation graph on this custom log based metric.

Comment: Thank you. This works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the inserted count for a table by monitoring big query logs and creating specific sinks. When a big query job that loads data into a table has run, we can look at below logs

[image]

The highlighted log provides the details about the number of records inserted into the table as part of batch process.

Below filter can be used to get specific logs

```
resource.type="bigquery_dataset" resource.labels.dataset_id="demo_dataset"
protoPayload.methodName="google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob"
protoPayload.resourceName: "projects/graphical-reach-285218/datasets/demo_dataset/tables/crime"
protoPayload.metadata.tableDataChange.reason="QUERY"
```

A sink can be created for this specific log which will be routed to big query dataset as shown  below

[image]

This table shown is not partitioned but can be partitioned by specifying the option while creating sink.

Every time the job is triggered and data is loaded in a table as below

[image]

The value for insertedRowsCount can be extracted by using standard SQL String functions.

Comment: Yes. This helps me a lot in solving my issue. Amazing solution to get the inserted count.